# pandas read tree like data into one column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I got a dataframe like this

```
    Country State   City    District    GeoID
0   US  NaN NaN NaN 1000000
1   US  California  NaN NaN 1010000
2   US  California  San Francisco   NaN 1011000
3   US  California  San Francisco   Hayes Valley    1011001
4   US  California  San Francisco   South of Market 1011002
5   US  California  San Francisco   Potrero Hill    1011003
6   US  California  San Francisco   Russian Hill    1011004
7   US  California  San Francisco   Noe Valley  1011005
8   US  California  San Diego   NaN 1012000
9   US  California  San Diego   Communities of Clairemont   1012001
10  US  California  San Diego   Linda Vista 1012002
11  US  California  San Diego   Chollas View    1012003
12  US  California  San Diego   North Bay Terrace   1012004
13  US  California  San Diego   Valencia Park   1012005
14  US  California  San Diego   Lomita Village  1012006
15  US  California  Los Angeles NaN 1013000
```

I want to match GeoID with related info, if there are district match it first, then match city,state, and country.

Something like

```
for i in range(len(df["GeoID"])):
    if df["District"]==None:
      if df["City"]==None:
        if df["State"]==None:
            df["newGeo"]=df["Country"]
        else:
            df["newGeo"]=df["State"]
      else:
          df["newGeo"]=df["City"]
    else:
        df["newGeo"]=df["City"]
```

Desired output

```
GeoID newGeo
1000000 US
1010000 California
1011000 San Francisco
1011001 Hayes Valley
1011002 South of Market
1011003 Potrero Hill
1011004 Russia Hill
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would it be something like the following?

```
df['GeoID'] = df.fillna(method='ffill', axis=1).iloc[:,-2]
```

fillna with the method ffill propagates non-null values foward, and iloc will select the desired column. Let's say you have:

| index | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Country | NaN | NaN | 101 |
| 1 | Country | State 2 | NaN | 1101 |
| 2 | Country | State 3 | NaN | 10101 |
| 3 | Country | State 4 | City 4 | 101000 |
| 4 | Country | State 5 | City 5 | 1011 |

Using `df.fillna(method='ffill', axis=1)` will get you the following:

| index | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Country | Country | Country | 101 |
| 1 | Country | State 2 | State 2 | 1101 |
| 2 | Country | State 3 | State 3 | 10101 |
| 3 | Country | State 4 | City 4 | 101000 |
| 4 | Country | State 5 | City 5 | 1011 |

As you can see, it pushes the values that are not null forward. You can simply select that second to last column with `.iloc[:,-2]` and assign it to a new column with the full code above. The full result is:

| index | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | GeoID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Country | NaN | NaN | 101 | Country |
| 1 | Country | State 2 | NaN | 1101 | State 2 |
| 2 | Country | State 3 | NaN | 10101 | State 3 |
| 3 | Country | State 4 | City 4 | 101000 | City 4 |
| 4 | Country | State 5 | City 5 | 1011 | City 5 |

Answer (score 0):

Something like this can help your scenario:
It allows matching multiple column values 'and' in single statement

```
my_df.loc[ (my_df['my_column_1'] == my_condition_1) & (my_df['my_column_2'] == my_condition_2) & (my_df['my_column_3'] == my_condition_3)]
```

Please read about '.loc', '.iloc' in pandas
https://www.adamsmith.haus/python/answers/how-to-filter-a-pandas-dataframe-by-multiple-columns-in-python

Comment: df and df["col"] are different shape, I got an error running your method

Answer (score 0):

Just use fillna() with copy()

```
df=df1.copy()
df["State"]=df["State"].fillna(df["Country"]).copy()
df["City"]=df["City"].fillna(df["State"]).copy()
df["District"]=df["District"].fillna(df["City"]).copy()
df["new_Geo"]=df["District"].copy()
df1["new_Geo"]=df["new_Geo"]
df1

    Country State   City    District    GeoID   new_Geo
0   US  NaN NaN NaN 1000000 US
1   US  California  NaN NaN 1010000 California
2   US  California  San Francisco   NaN 1011000 San Francisco
3   US  California  San Francisco   Hayes Valley    1011001 Hayes Valley
4   US  California  San Francisco   South of Market 1011002 South of Market
5   US  California  San Francisco   Potrero Hill    1011003 Potrero Hill
6   US  California  San Francisco   Russian Hill    1011004 Russian Hill
7   US  California  San Francisco   Noe Valley  1011005 Noe Valley
8   US  California  San Diego   NaN 1012000 San Diego
9   US  California  San Diego   Communities of Clairemont   1012001 Communities of Clairemont
10  US  California  San Diego   Linda Vista 1012002 Linda Vista
11  US  California  San Diego   Chollas View    1012003 Chollas View
12  US  California  San Diego   North Bay Terrace   1012004 North Bay Terrace
13  US  California  San Diego   Valencia Park   1012005 Valencia Park
14  US  California  San Diego   Lomita Village  1012006 Lomita Village
15  US  California  Los Angeles NaN 1013000 Los Angeles
```